# Solving Product for X

Tags: products

I have a question about Products written with Product signs. 
Can I simplify that and if yes how can I do that? I tried various ways but I didn‘t figured out.
$$ \prod _{n=0}^{x-1} x-n $$
$$ \prod _{n=1}^{x} \sin(x\cdot n) $$

Comment: i think the first productory is just the $x!$, cause at $x - 1$ you have $(x - (x - 1)) = 1, (x - (x - 2)) = 2$, and $(x - 0) = x$, wich prety sure the definition of fatorial.

Comment: Hello, for the first one, notice that by inverting the order of the product (which you can do because the product is commutative in $\mathbb{R}$) you get the factorial :

$$\prod_{n=0}^{x-1} (x-n) = \prod_{n=1}^x n = x! $$

For the second one, I don't know any nice formula to simplify this, why do you need it ?

Comment: What does the product mean if $x$ is not an integer?  It's like a summation sign; the indices are integers.

Comment: Okay, thanks for $ x! $. I‘ve thought of some exponential function, but yes.

Comment: And for the second one, I‘ve just wondered why it‘s so complicated to simplify $\sin(\alpha) \cdot \sin(\beta) $. Then I‘ve thought maybe you can simplify it when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are somehow connected by a pattern. I don‘t need it for $\sin ( x \cdot n )$.  $\sin ( f(x,n) $ is also fine, but I think that‘s a bit harder.